# How to escape single quotes in Shell FFmpeg?

Tags: c, bash, shell, ffmpeg, zsh

### My environment

- zsh
- Apple clang version 13.0.0

### Summary of my problem

I want to draw some text on a video using FFmpeg.

My command line is sent by a C program with the system() function.

When there is a single quote in my string, the text does not display, which makes sense.

### What I've tried

- Leaving it as it is → no text is drawn
- Escaping it normally with \' → no text is drawn
- Double escaping it with \\' → no text is drawn
- Triple escaping it, etc...
- Using the `\0027` and `\xE2\x80\x99` notations → text is drawn as "0027" or "xE2x80x99"

### My code

**The generateVideo() function**

```
void generateVideo(char sourceVideoPath[], char text[], int destinationFileName) {
    char line[1000];
    sprintf(line, "ffmpeg -i %s -vf \"drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font/:text='%s':fontcolor=white:fontsize=28:borderw=2.8:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2\" -codec:a copy ../%d.mp4", sourceVideoPath, text, destinationFileName);
    system(line);
}
```

I don't know if the problem comes from FFmpeg or Shell, but it is a pain that I can't draw texts with quotes for the moment.

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Why is this tagged _bash_ **and** _zsh_? From your code, it doesn't look that either _bash_ or _zsh_ would be invoked, but this depends on the implementation of the library you use with the C compiler. Also, for debugging, I would print the value of `line`. I also suggest that you post your operating environment and the version of your C compiler.

Comment: I use the zsh shell, but there may be the same issue for bash users. I already printed `line` and it is fine, I think the problem really is with FFmpeg or Shell. I edited my post for precisions, thanks for telling!

Comment: I don't care what **you** are using for calling your C program. I'm talking about what shell your C program is using. `system` may, depending on the implementation, use POSIX shell (`sh`), or it may check the environment variable `SHELL` to see what shell to use. In both cases, it is not guaranteed that it will use `zsh`. I don't say that the difference matters in your simple case, but you should be aware of it anyway - in particular, since zsh is pretty different from sh and bash.

Comment: I see. `system("echo $0")` returned `sh`

Comment: What I would do next is to start manually an interactive `sh` and copy and paste the command you have on your variable `line` into this shell and check what it is doing.

Comment: You have a single command, not a more complicated shell construct. I would ditch `system`, use `fork`, then use an appropriate `exec` function to execute `ffmpeg` with an appropriate array of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell from your question what the problem is, but I believe a fix like encoding \ before the quotes in the text should fix it. It might be easier to help if you started from a command line that works from the shell and then tried to issue that command with 'system' from your C code. Here is a main.c that demonstrates what I think ought to work:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *sourceVideoPath = "video";
    char *text = "text \\'quoted\\' text";
    int destinationFileName = 10;
    char line[1000];
    sprintf(line, "echo ffmpeg -i %s -vf \"drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font/:text='%s':fontcolor=white:fontsize=28:borderw=2.8:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2\" -codec:a copy ../%d.mp4", sourceVideoPath, text, destinationFileName);
    system(line);
}
```

Comment: Echoing this works and outputs "text \'quoted\' text", but when actually executing the line, it still returns a blank text...
Thanks for the help still!

Comment: I still think your easiest path to getting this working is to run /bin/sh and make a working command line there first. Then figure out how to get your C program to create the same command line.

Or, the fork suggestion of another commenter is a good approach, but quite different than what you've attempted here.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *sourceVideoPath = "video.mp4";
    char *text = "'text '\\\\\\\\\\\''quoted'\\\\\\\\\\\'' text'";
    char *destinationFileName = "with_text.mp4";
    char line[1000];
    sprintf(line, "ffmpeg -i \"%s\" -vf \"drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/fonts/font.ttf:text=%s:fontcolor=white:fontsize=28:borderw=2.8:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2\" -codec:a copy \"%s\"", sourceVideoPath, text, destinationFileName);
    system(line);
}
```

I'm not joking :).
Tested with an actual video file.

Comment: I can't believe this almost works! But it displays only the second quote for some reason... https://imgur.com/IB9gBq1

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I can't figure out why the first one is not displayed... :( It's working fine on my environment.